# Easy Practice Test Problem Help

Tags: combinations

I am completing a practice math test, so I know the answer to the following problem (10), but I'm not sure how you would get it, and how it would apply for a different situation.

A group of five friends has two tickets to the ball game. How many different
combinations of these five friends can use the tickets?

I have experimented and come to the answer using $4+3+2+1$, but I am unsure if that's anywhere close to being right, and how it would apply if there were a different number of tickets, etc.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It is correct, however there is a much faster much easier way of seeing why it would be $10$ instead of adding several numbers together by looking at it using [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  You have **five** people.  You want to **choose two** of them to get tickets.  The number of ways this can be done then is "*five choose two*", i.e. $\binom{5}{2}=\frac{5!}{2!(5-2)!}=10$ ways.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the help

Comment: Just to make sure that you followed my previous comment and understood, can you now answer the question "*A group of eight friends have three tickets to the ball game.  How many different combinations of these eight friends can use the tickets?*"

Comment: @JMoravitz The answer would be 56 ways. Thanks again.